# In Jade, how can you call a function in an external Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

In /javascripts/showlist.js I have (plus some more not shown)

```
var interestMap = gets loaded from localStorage...

function getInterest(id) {
   return interestMap[id] || '';
}
```

My showlist.jade file looks like: (greatly simplified, it gets passed in an array of dogshows in the variable "shows")

```
extends layout

script(src='/javascripts/showlist.js')

block content

  table#showtable.sortable
    thead
      tr
         td... (column headers such as date and location, many are sortable)
    tbody
      each show in shows
         - var interest = getInterest(show._id);  <<< JADE problem here
         tr
           td... (various values, including)
           td =interest   // maybe this should be #{interest}
```

but I get "undefined is not a function" when I try to call getInterest().  So it's not seeing it.  I've also tried a slight mod to the external javascript

```
var getInterest = function(id) { ... }
```

and putting the getInterest code inline, neither with any success.

Note that the base layout this is extending has `doctype 5` as it's first line.

How do you call an external (or, I'll even settle for an internal) javascript function from Jade.  Or am I missing something simple and silly?  I did try "../javascripts/showlist.js" too.

Comment: Is your public directory accessible from this file? We are talking about a client side function `getInterest()`, right? not a server side function?

Comment: Yes, it's a client side function.  (Since it's reading localStorage it has to be client side).  It;s just running on my home computer in development so should be no accessibility issues, right?

Comment: did you setup your http server to have access to a static directory relative to your application or even in your application folder?? Are you using express.js??

Comment: I'm using Express.  Not sure what the first question means or why it's relevant to the client side.  But it's the pretty standard Express setup with public folder for static files like 404s.

Comment: Lacking the static public configuration is a common problem. Not your case here, just asking preliminary questions. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to call a client side function on the server side. Which is why it is coming back as undefined. It doesn't exist here.

Your jade `script()` tag is simply outputting a `<script>` tag to the page - it is not running it server side. To do that, you'd be using `require()` instead.

Since you are referring to localStorage, you cant simply copy the function on the server side and execute it there too.

You can, however, update your `showlist.js` so that on dom ready it updates the `td`s with their interest value. Add a html5 data attribute to your td with the show id. eg.

```
td(data-show-id=show._id)
```

Then find `td`s that need updating and call getInterest():

```
$('td[data-show-id]').each(function(index){
    var $el = $(this);
    $el.val(getInterest($el.data('show-id')));
});
```

Presuming you are running jQuery.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll give the @Seth answer a try but this, alas, feels correct.  I am now 0 for 2 at realizing where I am (server or client) in the Jade World.  Can I get a bronzed Statue of Liberty and Zeppelins to help tell them apart?

Comment: Slapping the `script` tag in the content block would presumably output it inside your `body` tag in the middle of the page, depending on how your layout is configured. You should add a `block js` and add it to either the `head` or at the end of the layout to output it before the closing `/body` tag

Comment: I'm not using this exact code, but the concept works.  Thanks!