# Proper way to call javascript function in EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

How can I properly call a javascript function to act on a value coming from EJS code block? My situation is on the front end, where I am parsing a value with a forEach... loop and I want to format a variable with a function I declared in another js file that I included before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jade: load external javascript and call function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26702006/jade-load-external-javascript-and-call-function)